# Is there ability to deploy a wordpress page/pages inside of another engine site

Tags: php, wordpress

Apprecaite any help on my question. 
Lets pretend, I have a internet shop driven on joomla or some another engine. Can i make a part of it on wordpress, for example, the page for every item in the shop? Dont take a look to the oddness of situation :) just want to know is there ability to cross engines. Also, if you can, please recommend manuals.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can as exhibited in this WordPress Codex [page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) but you will not be able to take advantage of the WordPress URL routing scheme, WordPress themes, plugins or widgets -- not directly -- you'll have to write custom code to use them.

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

You will just have access to the WordPress functions with which you will be able to fetch posts from the DB and then you will be able to write custom PHP code to display those posts.

Obviously displaying plugins or widgets will also become your responsibility -- you'll have to call functions which either render all plugins or fetch a list of plugins/widgets and decide what to do with them.